# Authentication of Micro Frontend(Idaas)

Tags: angular, authentication, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular15

I am currently transforming my application into a microfrontend.

As a result, I am looking for advice regarding how to handle Authorization / Authentication for the Microfrontends

How should authorization and authentication be handled in a shared microfrontend?
In what way should the shell load / call the Microfrontend with permissions?